# For interfaces with one implementation how can I just directly go to that implementation?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I often have to debug Java code which was written so that there is an interface and exactly one implementation of that interface.

For instance there would be an interface Foo with exactly one implementation called `FooImpl`. In the following code if I Ctrl-click on `doThings` it'll jump to `Foo.java` when I actually want to go to `FooImpl.java` to see the implementation.

```
public void doStuff(Foo foo) {
    foo.doThings();
}
```

When I end up at the interface I have to use Ctrl-Shift-R to open up `FooImpl`. It'd be really nice if I could do something lick Ctrl-Alt-click on `doThings` and end up inside `FooImpl.java`. If there are multiple implementations in the workspace then perhaps it would just pop up a box telling me what they are.

Is there a plugin or existing function in eclipse that does this? I know that I could go to `Foo.java` and then get the hierarchy and go to the implementation, but that's more clicks than are necessary when there is exactly one implementation of an interface.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in Netbeans?

Comment: @Tnay http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaGoToImplementation

Comment: there is one plugin, which makes "open implementation" easier.http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/implementors/download.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Implementors](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/implementors/) plugin does pretty much exactly what you ask for. If there is only one implementation it will open it directly, otherwise it will let you choose.

Comment: The solutions provided by meritron and Stephen both work great, but your solution gives me exactly what I want! I can hit a key and jump to the implementation! It defaults apparently to mapping to alt-f3, but I changed it to be ctrl-alt-t so that it works alongside the solution provided by meritron. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! The default keyboard shortcut to open a declaration is F3, so I guess that's why the plugin authors chose Alt+F3 for their similar functionality, but naturally you can choose whatever suits you best.

Comment: @Micke Will that plugin works on latest eclipse versions like `Luna` and `Mars`

Comment: this plugin does not suport newer eclipse. Look for better solution from @morgan-courbet below.

Comment: in a more complicated classes and interfaces hierarchy it displays just the top most implementation, not the one I expect

Answer (score 58):

1. Move the cursor to the method call
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
3. Select your desired implementation
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This also works if there are several implementors.

Comment: holy crap, I've been wondering how to do this for years, thank you so much! seems so obvious in retrospect

Comment: That works great! It'd be even better if it just jumped directly to the implementation if their is only one implementation, but it's a lot better than what I was doing.

Comment: As @StephenDenne pointed out, when you Ctrl + hover over the name of a method of an interface, you can select either "Open Declaration" or "Open Implementation."  If you choose the latter, it will jump straight to the only implementing class or (if there are multiple) open the Type Hierarchy so that you can choose which implementation class you want to jump into.

Answer (score 29):

Go to *Window* > *Preferences* > *General* > *Editors* > *Text Editors* > *Hyperlinking*, and uncheck *Open Declaration*.
[image: Preferences screenshot]

From now on, when you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while hovering over a method name, the following popup will be displayed. Just click on the method name and the implementation will be opened (or a *Types implementing XXX* box, if more than one implementation exists).

[image: Popup box]

You will still be able to use the *Open Declaration* feature by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: THIS is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

In Eclipse 3.5, when you hover over `doThings` while holding down the control key, a pop up box gives you two options to click on:

- Open Declaration
- Open Implementation

There's a screenshot as the second section of the [Eclipse 3.5 New & Noteworthy page for JDT](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-part2.html):

[image]

Comment: Excellent tip. I would like to add that you can easily bind this to a key under Preferences -> General -> Keys -> "Open Implementation".
This mimics the implementors plugin which is now be obsolete IMHO.

Comment: This feature is called Hyperlinking.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) I saw <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (Toggle Source/Header) which worked for me (although not directly but its a workaround).

[image: Toggle Source/Header]