# Jump into interface implementation in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, interface, polymorphism

You know how in Eclipse, pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> over a method will take you to its declaration? Well I have a method that is part of an interface; clicking <kbd>F3</kbd> over this naturally takes me to the declaring interface.

Obviously there is an object implementing this interface and this is where the method is actually implemented.  I want, when I press <kbd>F3</kbd>, to jump to the implementation, not the interface declaration. I know that the implementation may not be known at compile-time, so is there a way for Eclipse to show me all the classes implementing the interface so that I can select which implemented method to view? Right now when this happens I am just manually searching for this to find the implemented method.

Comment: Ctrl+T gives you a popup, F4 opens a window

Comment: Everything is slightly inconvenient to do in Java. Try .NET 6 on Visual Studio, it's a million times better experience. :)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Here's what I do:

- In the interface, move the cursor to the method name. Press <kbd>F4</kbd>. => Type Hierarchy view appears
- In the lower part of the view, the method should already be selected. In its toolbar, click "Lock view and show members in hierarchy" (should be the leftmost toolbar icon).
- In the upper part of the view, you can browse through all implementations of the method.

The procedure isn't very quick, but it gives you a good overview.

Answer (score 133):

Well... well... I hope you use Eclipse Helios, because what you asked is available on Helios.

Put your text cursor again on the method and click menu Navigate → Open Implementation. Now if you have more than one implementation of the method, you will get choice to pick which implementation to open.

[image]

By defining a keybinding on Preferences → General → Keys you can even use the feature easier, but before you do that, see if this shortcut is fast enough for you.

Press Ctrl + click and hold. Now move your mouse over the same method. Tadam… you will get choice.

[image]

If you pick Open Implementation you’ll get the same choice as before.

Comment: Fantastic. This solves something that has always bugged me about eclipse. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great tip! but also you may just hover cursor over and press ctrl then select from dropdown [in eclipse oxygen].... I mean you may not need to hold ctrl + click now.

Answer (score 80):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on the method name (rather than <kbd>F3</kbd>). This gives the type hierarchy as a pop-up so is slightly faster than using <kbd>F4</kbd> and the type hierarchy view.

Also, when done on a method, subtypes that don't implement/override the method will be greyed out, and when you double click on a class in the list it will take you straight to the method in that class.

Comment: Works also great with keyboard-only. Just CTRL+T and use arrow keys to navigate. Press Enter to jump to the implementation.

Answer (score 55):

There's a big productivity boost if you add an <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> key binding to the Open Implementation feature, and just use <kbd>F3</kbd> to go to interfaces, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to go to implementations.

[image: Open implementation keybinding]

Comment: Great tip ! Thanks. Just sad that eclipse searches only one level of hierarchy though.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Many of the others (especially the pluggins) did not.

Comment: In Eclipse Neon Alt+F3 is used for `Incremental Find`, I chose Alt+I instead

Answer (score 15):

Highlight an interface and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open "Quick Type Hierarchy".

Answer (score 14):

```
ctrl + mouse hover + click "Open Implementation"
```

On `ctrl + hover`, you should see the following menu:

[image]

Tested on Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I do:

I press command (on Mac, probably control on PC) and then hover over the method or class.  When you do this a popup window will appear with the choices "Open Declaration", "Open Implementation", "Open Return Type".  You can then click on what you want and Eclipse brings you right there.  I believe this works for version 3.6 and up.

It is just as quick as IntelliJ I think.

Answer (score 2):

See [In eclipse, ctrl-click goes to the declaration of the method I clicked. For interfaces with one implementation, how can I just directly to that implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105979/in-eclipse-ctrl-click-goes-to-the-declaration-of-the-method-i-clicked-for-inter) for some alternative solutions.

- Anyway, I think you might be looking for something like this:

http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/implementors/

Comment: Thanks this was helpful too.  From that link you can also click on the method while hold down 'cntrl' and then choose 'Open Implementation'.  This is even faster.

Answer (score 2):

I always use this implementors plugin to find all the implementation of an Interface

http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/updates/

it's my favorite and the best

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking to speed your code navigation, you might want to take a look at [nWire for Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java). It is a code exploration plugin for Eclipse. You can instantly see all the related artifacts. So, in that case, you will focus on the method call and instantly see all possible implementations, declarations, invocations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.