# how to debug sun.security package in eclipse

Tags: java, security

I want to debug `sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory`source code with eclipse, but how ?

```
ProviderConfig: Loading provider: sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
Provider: Set SunRsaSign provider property     [KeyFactory.RSA/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory]
Provider: Set SunRsaSign provider property     [KeyPairGenerator.RSA/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator]
Provider: Set SunRsaSign provider property     [Signature.MD2withRSA/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA]
Provider: Set SunRsaSign provider property     [Signature.MD5withRSA/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA]
Provider: Set SunRsaSign provider property     [Signature.SHA1withRSA/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA]
Provider: Set SunRsaSign provider property     [Signature.SHA256withRSA/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA256withRSA]
Provider: Set SunRsaSign provider property     [Signature.SHA384withRSA/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA384withRSA]
Provider: Set SunRsaSign provider property     [Signature.SHA512withRSA/sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA512withRSA]
Provider: Set SunRsaSign provider property     [Signature.MD2withRSA SupportedKeyClasses/java.security.interfaces.]
```

Comment: its all gibberish, can you format the text properly and post it? you can put the error message in the `code block`

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you even trying to debug code written by Sun/Oracle?

Comment: I had same problem. Solved by downloading RHEL's package OpenJDK

Answer (score 4):

### Not all sources with jdk

Some people say that sources should be included with jdk's src.zip file.

This is what I got in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\src.zip\com\sun\security

```
auth
jgss
```

So there is no `provider` directory nor `rsa` etc.

### Solution

You can see the file source [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/rsa/RSAKeyFactory.java).

To get it working in Eclipse using F3, download the [zipped source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/archive/tip.zip). Rename it to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\src.zip
```

Linux's jdk src.zip is also [incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732226/where-do-i-find-the-java-jdk-source-code-for-jdk-1-8).

### Eclipse settings

- If you cannot find the declaration with F3 in Eclipse try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157597/attach-the-java-source-code/14879501#14879501)
- Also if you want to open implementation declaration try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255530/jump-into-interface-implementation-in-eclipse-ide/6730788#6730788)