# How to get eclipse to go to the ONLY implementation of an interface's method?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

If I'm in an interface and pointing to a method name, what can I do to quickly go to the ONLY implementation of that method?

Using Eclipse 3.6.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I just checked this on my Eclipse 3.6 install: Hold control (command on Mac), hover over the method name and select "Open Implementation".

You may assign a keyboard shortcut to this action by using Window > Preferences > General > Keys and searching for "Open Implementation".

Comment: You might also want to change that key binding's scope ('When') to 'Editing Java Source` or something.

Comment: This works perfectly fine unless u have to be switching between machines that are used by several users...RIP no mouse users...

Comment: this will save me a lot of clicks ! thanks for sharing !

Answer (score 129):

<kbd>F3</kbd> is the typical "go to implementation".  For interfaces that go to the *interface* definition.

Instead use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to see all implementations of the interface definition.  You can then easily go to the one you want with the arrow keys and Enter.  I believe that the first one is automatically selected so that <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will do what you need.

Comment: Ctrl-T + Enter doesn't work in my case. The default focus is the filter text box. Thus, this combined keys just opens the interface.

Comment: @TheSea Ctrl-T + Arrow down + Enter perhaps then?

Comment: Yes. However, Arrow down + Enter is pretty expensive when we are reading code. Especially, after pressing Ctrl + T,  Eclipse search all the implementations in the workspace which causes some unpredictable delay :)

Comment: @TheSea I have since switched to IntelliJ which does this much much better.

Answer (score 25):

In the keymap (General > Keys) search for "open implementation" and map it to whatever you want.  I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.  Make sure you select "Editing Java Source" in the When box.  I tested it, and having the cursor over the method name and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> took me directly to the implementation instead of showing the hierarchy that you get with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

Also you can see an answer to a nearly identical question for other options:

- [In eclipse, ctrl-click goes to the declaration of the method I clicked. For interfaces with one implementation, how can I just directly to that implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105979/in-eclipse-ctrl-click-goes-to-the-declaration-of-the-method-i-clicked-for-inter)

Comment: Note that we can actually keep the original F3 key rather than having to invent some extra nonstandard key: if we assign F3 to "Open implementation" with "When = Editing Java Source", there is no conflict with the original F3 "Open declaration" with "When = In Windows"

Comment: Further note: "Ctrl + Shift + I"  is already taken by the debugger's Inspect expression command.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still need this information nowadays (Eclipse version 2022), to jump into interface method definition starting from an @Override method, now in Eclipse you can see on the left, next to the method signature, a little white triangle. By clicking on that you will jump to the implemented interface method. [here an image of the little triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1xBx.png)

Oterwise, if you are on a interface method definition and you need to jump to one of the implementations, you must use CTRL+T shortcut to see the list of available implementations and than click on one of them.