# Is it easy to find classes/methods references in IDEs that suppport Spring

Tags: spring, ide, reference, configuration-files

I have years of Java experience on Eclipse and now would like to get my feet wet with Spring. After read some tutorials I have such a question: is it easy (or even possible) to find classes/methods references in any IDE that supports Spring? By using Spring there should be no direct references among some classes, instead they are configured in xml files.

Even further: how to manage those xml files if my project gets large, say with thousands or hundreds classes? I mean perhaps it is easy to get lost among those complicated configuration files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2106009/106261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is a dependency injection engine. This means that it injects instances of A into beans which are dependent on A. So if bean B has a dependency on A, it will have a field of type A, and Spring will initialize this field for you.

Finding the references is thus trivial: select one of A's methods, choose "Call hierarchy", and if B calls this method of A, Eclipse will find it. It's not different from any other Java project not using Spring.

Regarding the size of the XML files, Spring also uses annotations to inject beans, so the XML file can be reduced to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

With [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) or the Spring-IDE plugin, it is possible to click on the class definition in the spring xml file and you will be direcly "forwarded" to the class.

And for example you build a view where the bean instances are displayed in an uml like class diagram. To get an overview how which bean is connected to other once.

*But really you will not need that.
If you implement against an interface then it should not matter which concrete class is implementing the interface.
And if you implement against an class, then you know that class already.*