# Eclipse CDT: Can't navigate from method declaration to implementation

Tags: eclipse, navigation, implementation, declaration, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing C++ under Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7.

I've noticed I can't easily navigate from a method declaration to its corresponding implementation. I've seen the following post, and installed the Implementors  plugin, but it doesn't seem to make any difference:
[In eclipse, ctrl-click goes to the declaration of the method I clicked. For interfaces with one implementation, how can I just directly to that implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105979/in-eclipse-ctrl-click-goes-to-the-declaration-of-the-method-i-clicked-for-inte)
Edit: I just checked, and it wasn't included in the list of installed plugins. I retried and it doesn't seem to install into the registry under Windows.

From googling elsewhere, I've read that another option should be to hover over the method declaration, and then select F2 to bring the implementation into focus, but this displays a opo-up with the same method declaration, not its implementation.

On right-clicking the method declaration in the .h file, I can select Toggle Source/Header, and this opens the .cpp file in another another tab, but it doesn't navigate to the method implementation .

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you try F3 or Ctrl+click to the declaration?