# Eclipse - change order for Open Declaration / Implementation / Return Type

Tags: java, eclipse, hyperlink, ide, eclipse-luna

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the mouse is over a method call, a menu is opened:

> Open Declaration
>
> Open Implementation
>
> Open Return Type

If I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **click** on the method call, the first option will be considered (Open Declaration).

I want to change the order of these options to:

> Open Implementation
>
> Open Declaration
>
> Open Return Type

Is it possible to achieve the second order? ( or to let them in the same order but change "the default" for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **click** to be **Open Implementation** )

I know that I can uncheck the "Open Declaration" from *Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Hyperlinking* , but I'd like to have all options there with **Open Implementation** as default.

### Details

- O.S.: **Windows 7**
- IDE: **Eclipse Luna (4.4)**
- Picture (default):

  [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can re-order the priorities, but as a workaround you can change the modifier keys for **Open Implementation** so that you can invoke it directly without the other options getting in the way. In the Preferences dialog, search for "hyper" in the search box (without the quotes), select **Hyperlinking** and then select the **Open Implementation** entry. At the bottom of the list, you can change the modifiers (for example, I set it to Ctrl + Alt).

[image]

Comment: This approach is better for the situation above with a small change: Open Implementation -> Ctrl and Open Declaration -> Ctrl + Alt. :)

Answer (score 5):

An answer to a similar question may also work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2106233/2683059

It suggests you try a plug-in for eclipse - http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/implementors/ which will enable the functionality you are looking for.

**Instructions:**

In Eclipse select Help > Install new software

click 'Add' to add a new update site and enter http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/updates/

in the Filter box type 'Implementors'

check the plug-in and click Next > then complete the install

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks JNYRanger.  I have now added more detail so that users know how to install the plug-in which provides this feature.